# Use a taglib variable in jsp

Tags: taglib, custom-tags

I am using taglib.
I have the following java code.
`int i=0;

public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {

        i= 1; //I do some process and get a value for i

        super.doTag();

    }`

I have defined a tld file for accessing the code in jsp file.
My doubt is that how do i access the value i in my jsp file.
I dont want to use the `getJspContext().getOut().print(i)` which will print the value of i.

Thanks.

Comment: You can make you variable static and get like this: yourClassName.yourVariableName;

Comment: I need to access the variable in jsp. The above is a taglib. I will be accessing it like <custom:tagForI value="10">

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465936/very-simple-custom-taglib-function-not-working